# Trying to add graphic to query result

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and have some code that zooms to a query results extent, but I also want to highlight the query result.

Console.log shows I'm returning an object but I can't seem to add the "highlightSymbol" to it.

```
//add the layers
map.addLayer(topoBasemap);
map.addLayers([administrative,parcels, agriculture, transportation]);

//set extent
var startext = new esri.geometry.Extent({
        "xmin" : 186870.18,
        "ymin" : 541462.48,
        "xmax" : 735481.291,
        "ymax" : 967243.73,
        "spatialReference" : {
            "wkid" : 102711
        }
    });
map.setExtent(startext);

//get extent info
map.on("extent-change",
    function findExtent() {
    var e = map.extent;
    var s = "";
    s = "<b>XMin:</b> " + e.xmin + "<br/>" +
        " <b>YMin:</b> " + e.ymin + "<br/>" +
        " <b>XMax:</b> " + e.xmax + "<br/>" +
        " <b>YMax:</b> " + e.ymax + "<br/>" +
        " <b>Spatial Reference: (wkid)</b> " + e.spatialReference.wkid + "<br/>" +
        " <b>Center: (x,y)</b> " + e.getCenter().x + ", " + e.getCenter().y;
    dom.byId("onExtentChangeInfo").innerHTML = s;
    var d = "";
    d = "<b>Zoom Level:</b> " + map.getLevel() + "<br/>" +
        "<b>Resolution:</b> " + map.getResolution() + "<br/>" +
        "<b>Scale:</b> " + map.getScale() + "<br/>";
    dom.byId("details").innerHTML = d;
});

//Highlight Symbol
var highlightSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(
        SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
        new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new Color([255, 0, 0]), 3),
        new Color([125, 125, 125, 0.2]));

//Query BLOCK/LOT
var queryTask = new QueryTask(parcels.url);

var query = new Query();
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.outFields = ["*"];
on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", execute);

function execute() {
    map.graphics.clear();

    query.where = "SSN = '" + dijit.byId("muniSelect").value + "' AND BLOCK = '" + dom.byId("block").value + "' AND LOT = '" + dom.byId("lot").value + "'";
    queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
}
function showResults(results) {
    var resultItems = [];
    var resultCount = results.features.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
        var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
        for (var attr in featureAttributes) {
            resultItems.push("<b>" + attr + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[attr] + "<br>");
        }
        resultItems.push("<br>");
    }
    if (resultCount === 0) {
        dom.byId("info").innerHTML = "<h3 style = 'color:#E60000'> No Record Found </h1>";
    } else {
        dom.byId("info").innerHTML = resultItems.join("");

        //Zoom to Result & Set Query Result Symbol
        var resultGraphic = new Graphic(results.features, highlightSymbol);
        var resultExtent = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(results.features);
        map.graphics.add(resultGraphic);
        map.setExtent(resultExtent.expand(2));

        console.log("resultGraphic:", (results.features));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

results.features is an array of features. Loop though this array to push every feature in map.graphics. Like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
  var resultGraphic = new Graphic(results.features[i], highlightSymbol);
  map.graphics.add(resultGraphic);
}

//replace this line with the above code 
var resultGraphic = new Graphic(results.features, highlightSymbol);
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working. Another question- what if I know I am only returning 1 feature and not an array? Is there a more simplistic way to go about doing this?

Comment: var resultGraphic = new Graphic(results.features[0], highlightSymbol); map.graphics.add(resultGraphic);